# How to deploy FLS (Field Level Security) for all Objects & Fields in Scratch Org with application source push?

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, field-level-security, fls

I'm trying to setup DX with Source code in Git and I'm pulling it from there and pushing it into a Scratch org. My Source code has multiple standard/custom objects with fields. But after Pushing code to scratch org, none of my fields have FLS set for them.

Even though I have a permission set with relevant Read/Edit permissions, still when my Lightning Component is reading the fields, I am unable to display the fields since the FLS is not set for the fields.

How do i overcome this? Default scratch org is set to run with User as System Administrator. And I really don't want to setup this up via manual task, I got over 35+ Custom Objects with at least 20-30 fields in each of them. it doesn't make sense to set FLS manually in each field for every scratch org given that it will expire after certain time and then again I've to redo the steps for FLS for new org.

Why didn't FLS permissions were set using Permission Set if it is assigned to user, and how can I enable FLS as part of my source push for at least System Administrator profile in the Scratch org during my initial source push?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm running into the same thing and thinking there has to be a better way to do this...

Comment: No, none so far :(

Comment: Permission Sets seems to work best so far, BUT biggest disappointment is, Page Layout Assignments do not work and all page layouts (if record types exist on objects) are messed up after refreshing a scratch org.

Comment: Yup. That's what I've found.  I need to solve the problem because it's a huge roadblock to transitioning from mdapi development into sfdx development.  I'll post an answer here if I ever find something...